# Switching between dblinks depending on date

Tags: oracle

The database was divided in two, one with information up to 2016 and the other with information from 2017 onwards.
The DBA created two dblinks: @old.com (<=2016) and @new.com (>2016).
I have some simple searches that depending on the date need to use the corresponding dblink.

`select * from user@old.com;`

or

`select * from user@new.com;`

I would not like to use "execute immediate" and concatenate the dblink. 
There is another way I can do this?

Comment: Will the date in question change over a Session?

Comment: Yes, it will change.

Comment: You can create a view that unions the selects from the old and new. You then just select from the view.